# How to output specific lines from a batch routine?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have the following batch script, iterating recursively on all files in a given folder:

```
FOR /R %%i IN ("*.wmv") DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zipa\7za.exe" a -mx0 -tzip -pPassword -mem=AES256 -y "%%~dpni.zip" "%%i"
```

that, when ran, it produces the following output per each file it works on:

```
 7-Zip (a) [64] 16.04 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-10-04

 Scanning the drive:
 1 file, 382316 bytes (374 KiB)

 Creating archive: C:\test\7208969.zip

 Items to compress: 1


 Files read from disk: 1
 Archive size: 382524 bytes (374 KiB)
 Everything is Ok
```

What I would like is to create an output text file that only contains these two lines per iteraction:

```
Creating archive: C:\test\7208969.zip
Everything is Ok
```

I've tried calling the main batch script from another batch using something like (this is just an illustrative example):

```
FOR /F "(tried with skip, delims, tokens, etc)" %%G IN ('7zip.bat') DO echo %%G
```

but all that I've tried ended up writing lots of weird stuff, except what I needed.

If anyone could enlighten me on how to accomplish this in any way, it'll be much appreciated!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pipe the output of your command in your loop with `findstr` and 2 expressions, one for each line.

```
FOR /R %%i IN ("*.wmv") DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zipa\7za.exe" a -mx0 -tzip -pPassword -mem=AES256 -y "%%~dpni.zip" "%%i" | findstr /C:"Creating archive" /C:"Everything"
```

At this point, I don't have the case where something goes wrong. Obviously you can add as many strings as you want:

```
... | findstr /C:"Creating archive" /C:"Everything is OK" /C:"Something went wrong"
```

Comment: Thanks a million!. You totally nailed it and with the outmost simplicity! =).
One thing that happened when I tried it is that if I use "Creating archive" it will not output that line, but when only using "Creating", it works like a charm.

Comment: Totally!. Sorry I didn't accept it before, I'm kinda new to this community. Thanks again! =)